# Are weakly compact cardinals preserved in arbitrary inner models?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, large-cardinals

It's well-known that if a cardinal is weakly compact, then it is weakly compact in $L$. Seems natural to ask if weak-compactness is preserved for arbitrary inner models. Since I've never heard this, I'm guessing the answer is no, but I'm having trouble finding a counterexample.

---

I have something that I *think* might work, but for the ZF version of the problem:

> Since it's assigned as an exercise in Jech's AC book I believe that
> "if $\kappa$ is weakly compact, then it's weakly compact in L" still
> holds in ZF. So let $\omega_1$ be weakly compact (which is consistent
> with ZF). Then, go to an $L[A]$ that correctly computes $\omega_1.$
> We'll have AC in $L[A]$, thus $\omega_1$ can't be weakly compact in
> $L[A].$
>
> (But is it consistent with $\omega_1$ being weakly compact that
> there's an $L[A]$ that correctly computes $\omega_1$? I think the
> latter requires some choice on the reals.)

If this works, then maybe we can get something in ZFC from the Jech
model (i.e. start with $\kappa$ weakly compact, collapse $\kappa$ to
be countable and symmetrize so that $\kappa$ is $\omega_1$ in the
symmetric submodel)... perhaps we can make some partial extension
where $\kappa$ isn't fully collapsed and is still weakly compact?

---

My question is mostly just the title. Would also appreciate feedback on my attempt. (But, even if viable, it seems convoluted, so would guess there's a better example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your argument is that if $\omega_1$ is weakly compact, then there is no $A$ such that $L[A]$ computes $\omega_1$ correctly. To see this, note that if $M$ is an inner model of $\sf ZFC$ which computes $\omega_1$ correctly, then $M$ knows a special Aronszajn tree (specifically the canonical construction of an Aronszajn tree using the rationals), but since in $V$ there are no such trees, the tree must have a branch, which must have collapsed $\omega_1$.

This is not too dissimilar from the case where $\omega_1$ is singular. Given any inner model of $\sf ZFC$, it cannot possibly compute $\omega_1$ correctly.

To your general question, it is not even necessarily the case that weak compactness is preserved into inner models of $\sf ZFC$. Case in point, start with $L$ where $\kappa$ is weakly compact, then using an Easton support iteration, add a Cohen subset to every regular cardinal below $\kappa$. This, in effect, adds a $\kappa$-Aronszajn tree, and so it kills the weak compactness of $\kappa$. However, if we add a Cohen subset to $\kappa$, effectively adding a branch through this tree, we resurrect the weak compactness of $\kappa$.

And so, we have $L\subseteq L[G_0]\subseteq L[G_0][G_1]$, where $\kappa$ is weakly compact in $L$ and in $L[G_0][G_1]$, but not in $L[G_0]$.

Comment: Is there generally a way like this to kill and resurrect a large cardinal? (When it’s not obviously impossible, like for inaccessibles.)

Comment: To an extent, yes, but it's kinda complicated and subtle. In principle you force with an iteration so that when you apply an elementary embedding you'd miss the generic at $\kappa$ so if you just add that generic, it will fix the problem. Of course, it's not that easy and it depends on the scenario exactly, but that's the general idea.